# How to programatically set Proxy Exception in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, proxy

I am trying to update programatically the Proxy Exception in IE (Tools -> Internet Options, Connections -> Lan Settings, Advanced and Exceptions), but I haven't been able to find the API and/or registry key. Anybody has an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to automate it with a batch file, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57145767/3733974

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're executing as the local user, the key is:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

Then the valuename is ProxyOverride and the value is a semi-colon seperated string of addresses or domains.