# Adding exception to Proxy Settings with a script in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, proxy

I am using Windows 7 and I have a proxy configuration which is initialized on startup. Each time I reboot my PC I have to reopen Proxy Settings and add new proxy exception ip addresses manually.

For example on each reboot

> www.google.com;www.yahoo.com;www.facebook.com

are already in exception list by default. Than I have to go to Proxy Settings and add

> www.addresfromscript.com; ip.from.script

by hand. On reboot ip addresses I entered are gone. I want to automate this task.

I need a Windows script to add proxy exceptions at startup. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with GUI programs.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4200279/6811411) to a similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically set Proxy Exception in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198410/how-to-programatically-set-proxy-exception-in-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an automation of this process, I'd rather make the changes permanent. Start **Regedit**, go to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings** and take a look at the entry **ProxyOverride**. There is a list of URLs separated with `;`. Just add the desired addresses, save the changes and restart windows.

However, if you still want to automate this registry change, you can export the modified value into a `.reg` file and create a batch with this line of code:

```
regedit <exported_reg_file>
```

Comment: @npocmaka I guess this is also possible. Something like `netsh winhttp set proxy bypass-list="ip.from.script.*"` and so on. Haven't tested, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate it with the windows batch file below.
It will read your proxy exception values stored in Registry and will append your list.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set key="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set value=ProxyOverride
:: websites you want to add into your proxy exceptions
set append=;www.addresfromscript.com; ip.from.script
:: getting current value of proxy exceptions
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %key% /v %value% 2^>nul`) DO (
    set Name=%%A
    set Type=%%B
    set CurrentValue=%%C
)

set NewValue=!CurrentValue!%append%
echo !NewValue!
:: Assigning new value. You can add /f if you want to remove overwriting confirmation
REG ADD %key% /v %value% /d "!NewValue!"
pause
```

ps: if you want to act safely, open the key **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings** into Registry Editor and copy the default value before running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with PowerShell too, with the following courtesy of https://sabrnet.wzk.cz/2019/02/how-to-modify-lan-proxy-exception-list-via-powershell/

```
$ProxyExceptionList = ";*.google.com;*.microsoft.com"

$ProxyProperty = Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"

If ($ProxyProperty.ProxyOverride) {
    $OldValue = $ProxyProperty.ProxyOverride
    $NewValue = $OldValue+$ProxyExceptionList
    $ProxyProperty | Set-ItemProperty -Name ProxyOverride -Value $NewValue
} else {
    Write-Warning "Proxy overrides not set!"
}
```